solucionar plugin de wordpress
Hola buen día con todos por lo menos con los que están viendo este mensaje eh básicamente tengo un error dentro del plugin que estoy usando el cual no me registra los usuarios que se registran en mi otra web y me genera este problema en el mismo; si bien tengo conocimiento en PHP por lo menos en estado básico no entiendo muy bien que debería hacer acá

bueno en la parte del codigo no note ningún problema por eso mismo es que quedo extrañado con el error , espero que si alguien tiene alguna idea me gustaria que me lo pudiera decir *es la primera vez que publico algo por aqui
bueno vi sus mensaje disculpen pense que habia subido el codigo me mame asi que lo estare poniendo por aca
<?php

/**
 * @package Gianvictor_Cueva
 * @version 1.1.1
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Gianvictor Cueva
Plugin URI: http://cuevatech.com/gianvictor-cueva/
Description: Gianvictor Cueva wordpress plugin
Author: Daniel Boggiano
Version: 1.1.1
Author URI: http://danielboggiano.com
*/

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if (!defined('WPINC')) {
    die;
}

/**
 * Currently plugin version.
 * Start at version 1.0.0 and use SemVer - https://semver.org
 * Rename this for your plugin and update it as you release new versions.
 */
define('GIANVICTOR_CUEVA', '1.1.1');
define('ANUAL_MEMBERSHIP', '1718');
define('API_KEY', 'fXDbeWLwZA1kHl0jDx5On0NG');

function impulse_apptrader_authentication($user, $email, $password)
{
    $error = new WP_Error();
    if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        $error  = new WP_Error('authentication_failed', __('ERROR: Invalid username or incorrect password.'));
        return $error;
    }

    if (email_exists($email)) {
        $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
        if (wp_check_password($password, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID)) {
            return new WP_User($user->ID);
        }
    }

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://qa.impulseworld.pro/bff/customer/auth/session/login',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
            "email": "' . $email . '",
            "password": "' . $password . '"
        }',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $data = json_decode($response);

    $success = $data->success;
    $token = $data->token;
    $first_name = $data->info->firstName;
    $last_name = $data->info->lastName;
    $customer_id = $data->info->customerid;

    if ($success && $token) {
        if (email_exists($email)) {
            $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
            if (wp_check_password($password, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID)) {
                return new WP_User($user->ID);
            }
        } else {
            $user_id = wp_create_user($email, $password, $email);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $first_name);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', $last_name);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'customer_id', $customer_id);
            return new WP_User($user_id);
        }
    }


    return new WP_Error('denegado', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.'));
}

add_filter('authenticate', 'impulse_apptrader_authentication', 10, 3);

function verify_api_key($request)
{
    $headers = $request->get_headers();
    $api_key = $headers['x_api_key'][0];
    if ($api_key != API_KEY) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function register_to_boletin($data)
{
    $email = $data['email'];
    $first_name = $data['firstName'];
    $last_name = $data['lastName'];
    $customer_id = $data['customerId'];

    $user = get_user_by('email', $email);

    if ($user->ID) {
        $membership = wc_memberships_get_user_membership($user->ID, ANUAL_MEMBERSHIP);
        if ($membership->id) {
            $update_args = array('ID' => $membership->id, 'post_status' => 'wcm-active');
            $result = wp_update_post($update_args);

            return array("success" => true, "message" => "Usuario actualizado", "result" => $result);
        } else {
            $args = array(
                'user_id' => $user->ID,
                'plan_id' => ANUAL_MEMBERSHIP,
            );

            wc_memberships_create_user_membership($args);

            return array("success" => true, "message" => "Usuario actualizado", "email" => $email);
        }
    } else {
        $password = wp_generate_password();
        $user_id = wp_create_user($email, $password, $email);

        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $first_name);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', $last_name);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'customer_id', $customer_id);

        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'plan_id' => ANUAL_MEMBERSHIP,
        );

        wc_memberships_create_user_membership($args);

        return array("success" => true, "message" => "Usuario creado", "email" => $email);
    }
}

function end_registration_to_boletin($data)
{
    $email = $data['email'];
    $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
    if ($user->ID) {

        $membership = wc_memberships_get_user_membership($user->ID, ANUAL_MEMBERSHIP);
        $status = 'wcm-paused';
        $update_args = array('ID' => $membership->id, 'post_status' => $status);

        $result = wp_update_post($update_args);

        return array("success" => true, "message" => "Usuario pausado", "result" => $result, "args" => $update_args);
    }
    return array("success" => false, "message" => "El usuario no existe");
}

function register_new_subscriber($data)
{
    $email = $data['email'];
    $first_name = $data['firstName'];
    $last_name = $data['lastName'];
    $customer_id = $data['customerId'];

    $user = get_user_by('email', $email);

    if ($user->ID) {
        return array("success" => true, "message" => "Usuario ya existe");
    } else {
        $password = wp_generate_password();
        $user_id = wp_create_user($email, $password, $email);

        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $first_name);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', $last_name);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'customer_id', $customer_id);

        return array("success" => true, "message" => "Usuario creado");
    }
}

function add_bolletin_endpoints()
{
    register_rest_route(
        'boletin/v1',
        '/enroll',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'register_to_boletin',
            'permission_callback' => 'verify_api_key',
        )
    );

    register_rest_route(
        'boletin/v1',
        '/pause',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'end_registration_to_boletin',
            'permission_callback' => 'verify_api_key',
        )
    );

    register_rest_route(
        'boletin/v1',
        '/register',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'register_new_subscriber',
            'permission_callback' => 'verify_api_key',
        )
    );
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'add_bolletin_endpoints');



Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! esos son errores.. y el codigo?? que trataste de arreglar???

Ya, y el codigo? que hay en esas lineas que menciona el error? por favor lee [ask]

Que te dice el soporte del plugin??

Haz un var_dump de la variable ( $data ) en la linea 66, parece que no esta devolviendo la respuesta correcta, verifica que devuelve y actualiza tu pregunta con ese log.

Una posibilidad es que $response no tenga la estructura que estás esperando. Para empezar el error dice que no tiene una propiedad token ni info. Si no tiene propiedad info malamente podrías leer firstName o lastName en ella
